# Magento - no mapping tables -> api endpoints

Tags: magento

I'm a newbie of Magento.
I need to export some table data out of magento, so I know I need to use the magento webapi.

I am able to get data from *sales_order* table through endpoint:
GET    /V1/orders
from devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html

I don't know where are the endpoints for: *sales_order_address* table, *sales_order_payent* table.

So please, can you show me where are them?

Comment: what is table data ? does it mean its structure ?

Comment: I mean the data in that table